# How to fire onClick function of a div depending on another div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to call a function on one type of button click on my HTML page.

I have got around 10 such button on the page and wrote the below code to call a function when the button is clicked,

```
$('.divname').each(function (index) {
    $(this).on("click", function (e) {
        //Call Another Function
    });
});
```

And this is working fine as expected.

However the issue is, sometimes depending on some condition one dynamically generated div is been created(Pop up message) and I dont want my above said code to work when the pop up message comes up.

Could you please advise how this can be achieved.

Thanks and Regards,
Aniket

Comment: My situation is - the onClick function is firing once the div is clicked and then the validation for another point is happening on the server side.Then again the onClick function fires(This is however stopped as I am doing this check). If the validation fails a pop up message comes up. So I need to stop firing the onClick function on the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi What something like set a bool and check if it true or false...somthing like:

```
var enable = true;

$('.divname').each(function (index) {
    $(this).on("click", function (e) {
        //Call Another Function
if(!enable) return;
    });
});

//set it to false on popup show (or something else event)
    $(popup).show(function(){
       enable = false;
    })
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried this but its not working.My situation is - the onClick function is firing once the div is clicked and then the validation for another point is happening on the server side.Then again the onClick function fires(This is however stopped as I am doing this check). If the validation fails a pop up message comes up. So I need to stop firing the onClick function on the first time.

Comment: so .. if i understando correctly .. try to invert my code.. $('.divname').each(function (index) {
    $(this).on("click", function (e) {
        //Call Another Function
if(!enable) return;  enable = false;
    });
});

Comment: then in the response frmo your sevrer side callback set it to true or false

Answer (score 0):

In simplest way.

```
$('.divname').each(function (index) {
    $(this).on("click", function (e) {
        //Simply check the condition for that Open Pop up message
       if(openPopUp){
       return;
       }
      callfunction();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried this but its not working.My situation is - the onClick function is firing once the div is clicked and then the validation for another point is happening on the server side.Then again the onClick function fires(This is however stopped as I am doing this check). If the validation fails a pop up message comes up. So I need to stop firing the onClick function on the first time.

Answer (score 0):

try something,

```
$('.divname').each(function (index) {
    $(this).on("click", function (e) {
       if($('#popupModal:visible').length == 0){ // check length of visible modals
        //Call Another Function
       }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I had tried this earlier. however the button click which for which I am creating the onClick function is having a server side checking and then the return value decides whether the pop up would come up or not. So whenever I am checking this option, its blocking the second time call(second time call was happening if I select Yes option from the pop up), which is fine but not blocking the 1st time call.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried this but its not working.My situation is - the onClick function is firing once the div is clicked and then the validation for another point is happening on the server side.Then again the onClick function fires(This is however stopped as I am doing this check). If the validation fails a pop up message comes up. So I need to stop firing the onClick function on the first time.